# How to read numeric data as uint8_t

Tags: c++, iostream

I have some human-readable numeric data in an `istream`. The values range from 0-255, and I want to store them in `uint8_t`. Unfortunately, if I try something like

```
uint8_t a, b;
stringstream data("124 67");
data >> a >> b;
```

then I end up with `a == '1'` and `b == '2'`. I understand that this is the desired behavior in many situations, but I want to end up with `a == 124` and `b == 67`. My current workaround is to stream the data into `int`s, then copy them to the `uint8_t`s.

```
uint8_t a, b;
int a_, b_;
stringstream data("124 67");
data >> a_ >> b_;
a = a_;
b = b_;
```

Clearly this gets very cumbersome (and slightly inefficient). Is there a cleaner way of reading numeric (as opposed to character) `uint8_t` data using `stream`s?

Answer (score 7):

You can't. `uint8_t` and `int8_t` are typedefs for `unsigned char` and `signed char` respectively. These types are treated as character types by iostreams and there's no way to change that behaviour.

Your second example is really the only way you can do this.