# How to read binary representation of uint8_t as a number

Tags: c++, binary

I write binary representation of a uint8_t sequence in file with the next code

```
uint8_t toStore;

std::fstream file("input", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
while(std::cin >> toStore) {
    file.write((char*)&toStore, sizeof(toStore));
}
file.close()
```

And then read it

```
file.open("input", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
file.read((char*)&toStore, sizeof(toStore));
while(!file.eof()) {
   std::cout << toStore << " ";
   file.read((char*)&toStore, sizeof(toStore));
}
file.close();
```

But when I read next sequence ("255 1 5", for example) which I write in a file with represented code with the above code I get

```
2 5 5 1 5
```

Instead of

```
255 1 5
```

Can I read a number sequence, not character?

Comment: The code **is** reading the number sequence. It's the output that's confusing things, because `uint8_t` seems to be a typedef for a `char`. When you insert a `char` into a stream you get the character that the value represents, and not the value. To see the values that you've gotten, cast the `uint8_t` to a larger type. I.e., `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(toStore)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both with reading `uint8_t` from `cin` and with writing it to `cout`.

Already discussed in many previous SO questions, e.g. [How to read numeric data as uint8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277218/how-to-read-numeric-data-as-uint8-t).

`uint8_t` and `int8_t` are typedefs for `unsigned char` and `signed char` respectively, thus treated by `istream` and `ostream` as `char`.

A possible solution:

```
bool read_one_byte(std::istream & is, uint8_t& out)
{
    short x;
    if (is >> x)
    {
        // can check here if number exceeds uint8_t ignore it or do something else...
        // current code doesn't check
        out = static_cast<uint8_t>(x);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void print_one_byte(std::ostream & os, uint8_t val)
{
    os << static_cast<short>(val);
}
```

Then use it:

```
int main() {
    uint8_t toStore;
    std::fstream file("input", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    while(read_one_byte(std::cin, toStore)) {
        uint8_t toStore2 = toStore;
        std::cout << "writing to file: " << (int)toStore2 << std::endl;
        file.write((char*)&toStore2, sizeof(toStore2));
    }
    file.close();
    file.open("input", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    std::cout << "reading from file: ";
    file.read((char*)&toStore, sizeof(toStore));
    while(!file.eof()) {
        print_one_byte(std::cout, toStore);
        std::cout << ' ';
        file.read((char*)&toStore, sizeof(toStore));
    }
    file.close();
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/839e2d495214a336